# Importing .sql file into SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to import a large .sql file into an SQLite .db file, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
sqlite> .read ./smsCorpus_en_2012.04.30.sql 
Error: near line 23: near "COMMENT": syntax error
Error: near line 50: near "LOCK": syntax error
Error: near line 52: near "some1": syntax error
Error: near line 58: near "s": syntax error
Error: near line 60: near "s": syntax error
Error: near line 66: near "UNLOCK": syntax error
```

The file is located at http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/data/corpus/smsCorpus_en_sql_2012.04.30.zip (direct file link) linked on this page http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/history.jsp

EDIT: just a warning, the file is quite large...not sure if this is the issue?

Answer (score 10):

That file is a MySQL dump.
To make SQLite understand it, you have to:

- delete `COMMENT`s on the table fields;
- remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` from `id` (`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` fields are autoincrementing in SQLite anyway);
- remove `ENGINE` and `DEFAULT CHARSET`;
- remove `LOCK`/`UNLOCK` commands;
- make the `INSERT` commands have fewer records;
- replace `\'` quoting with `''`.

Comment: Do you know of a way I can view this file? I don't seem to be able to open the whole thing and view it quickly, as it is a very large file...

Comment: I actually did try vim after posting, and it loaded it no problem, and I was able to fix the COMMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT, ENGINE, and LOCK/UNLOCK commands. The only problem I'm having now is finding the exact syntax errors on the massive lines (which likely have to do with single quotes in strings, but I can't exactly do a find/replace on single quotes...I need to learn more about using vim.

Comment: Look at the help for the `:s` command. You want something like `:%s/),(/);\rINSERT INTO mytable VALUES(/g` and `:%s,\\','',g`.

Answer (score 1):

That is a MySQL Dump and not SQLite.

There are slight variations on the syntax.

Comment: I had suspected this...is there any easy way to convert it?

Comment: Not really an easy way but you could manage it with a bit of trial and error. First thing to remove would be the comments on each of the field definitions. For example trimming off COMMENT 'Native speaker'.

Comment: Or if you're comfortable with Sqlite you could create the tables yourself matching the field names and delete the CREATE TABLE statements from the MySQL dump. I suspect the insert statements would be OK.