# How can I import 128 gb large .sql files into SQLite 3?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, split

I'm trying to import a very large .sql file into my database. The file is currently 128GB big. I

tried with the console MySQL

```
sqlite> .read db.sql
```

but this takes to long and hang my system and after 13 hours. it shows the process has been killed.

after that, I tried several options available on the internet but not getting any proper solution which helps me out.

please help me to import such a large file? I think splitting it is the way to go, but how can I split it correctly? It is only one table with several insert statements.

Comment: Do you have only the SQL file (I assume it contains `INSERT` statements) or do you have the data also in a plain CSV file?

Comment: How is your problem related to MySQL?

Comment: there @WernfriedDomscheit it contain commad of creating table and then insert commands

Comment: i want @ywwy i have large data which i want to transfer on my DB

Comment: It took me some time to understand your question.  Apparently 'db.sql' is a MySql file : [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920426/importing-sql-file-into-sqlite)

Comment: I don't understand if you want to transfer data from MySQL to SQLite or vice versa or if you use only one of these two. Anyway, create the data as CSV file, not SQL statements. Then you can use almost any scripting language (e.g. Perl) to parse the CSV and insert the data with prepared statement.

Comment: i can not convert it to CSV the file is too large